# Windows 7 current startup/shutdown bitmaps

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, bitmap, themes

Someone can tell me how to get CURRENTLY USED startup/shutdown bitmaps or animations of Windows 7 ? I know they are changed based on theme used. I am coding little tool to edit the current theme images, i dont want to use existing tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the logon screens? These dont change when you change the windows theme?

Comment: Just the images that are shown at logging on and at logging off/shutting down. To mention there are some circle animations from  what i see.

Comment: If you mean the loading animation, again, this doesnt change when you change the theme and its probably embedded in a resource file

Comment: I just want to be able to extract these images, for example the image you see on shutting down, background with version name of windows on the bottom and animated circle... i hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Red Serpent wrote in his comment, these background images are not part of the theme, instead they are provided by the OEM, hence won't change when you change Windows theme.

It is possible to change the login, logout and lock screen backgrounds independently from the current theme. You can achive this by altering a registry setting and creating/modifying some dedicated image files deep in the Windows folder. The required steps are described [in this blog post](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/change-and-customize-windows-7s-logon-screen-wallpaper/2135).

You can extract and change the OEM login screen background images by locating and reading these files. However, the default Windows 7 login screen cannot be extracted as it resides somewhere else, maybe bundled in a resource file with a dozen of other images.